# Drop table, Sql Compact edition

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

How do I drop Sqlce table from within VB Express 2008?

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992576/cant-drop-table-in-sqlce -- @bryce: Please don't double-post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a query?

```
Drop Table TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Thaks. That worked! Why doesn't it work if right click on the table in the database explorer and select drop table?

Comment: Not sure mate. Could be an issue with your SQL management studio. I have something similar where I go to open the properties of a SQL agent job and it opens up the new job dialogue. Strange eh!